# Gap between subfloor and wall

Tags: flooring, carpet

Updating a condo and had the carpet replaced in the bedroom.  Now that we're ready to install the trim we noticed that the carpet is curling down past the subfloor in one of the corners. There is a 3/4" gap that the carpet is curling down into (narrows on the other side).  What suggestions are there to remedy this before installing the base trim as it'll appear floating above the carpet?

Answer (score 1):

This gap, or curling under, is most likely due to the tack strip along the walls. This tack strip is what keeps the carpet down and stretched. Your trim will just go against the wall and down as far as you can get it to go.

Comment: Is there nothing that can be placed in the gap to stop this from happening?  In order to be level with the other walls a gap will appear between then trim and the carpet.

Comment: As Jeff answered this is fairly normal to have a gap the carpet goes into, if your base boards are narrow like quarter round I could see the problem but this trim is usually secured right at the carpet if the hole is wide not just the sheetrock you could try and pull the carpet and fill the floor to level with spackle, once dry put the carpet back and be good to go.

Comment: You could also add a piece of wood cut to size and thickness, pull the carpet up and glue, staple, nail, screw this down. Just as Ed said, just fill in the gap with a filler of some sort, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Always allow a 3/8 inch gap from the floor to the bottom of the baseboard to allow carpet to be tucked under. The tac board will be about an inch from the baseboards.